# Equation solver raises SyntaxError

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to make an equation solver that solves a given equation using loop

```
def eqn(step,dumbthing): #function supposed to solve an equation of proper syntax
x=-1000 #start at -1000
constant_value=(((dumbthing.replace(" ","")).replace("="," ")).split())[1] #constant value side (here, R.H.S) of the equation by splitting the two sides
equate=(((dumbthing.replace(" ","")).replace("="," ")).split())[0] #L.H.S
stuff=set("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm") #other stuff that are used as variables
for dumbstuff in stuff:
    equate=(equate.lower()).replace(dumbstuff,"x") #replace all types of stuff with "x"
realthing=dumbthing
while "xx" in realthing: #in case there is something like "pq" the replaced result will be "xx"
    realthing=realthing.replace("xx","x") #replace adjacent "xx"s with single "x"
while x<=1000: #solve equation by looping for x uptil 1000
    if eval(realthing)==eval(constant_value): #evaluate the two sides
        return x #return value of x
    x+=step #step is the step value of loop
print(eqn(1,"2*pq=8"))
```

However, the above code raises a SyntaxError instead of doing the job....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
File "<string>", line 12, in eqn
File "<string>", line 1
2*pq=8
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]
```

I have tried all sorts of ways, none of them seemed to work.
*Any help will be highly appreciated*

Comment: You are calling `eval()` on `realthing`, which is the full original equation (including that equals sign that doesn't mean the same thing in Python code), rather than `equate` which is just the LHS of the equation with all of your filtering applied to it.

Comment: Ah! I think i should do something like eqn(step,LHS,RHS), that works great! Thanks for the hint!!